# Spring Integration 4.1 - XML Validation Exception

Tags: xml, spring-integration

I am working with a huge ammount of XML's Schemas that serializes messages on Spring Integration, but sometimes SI fires an exception as described bellow.

But the problem is that on practice thousands of messages were created using the same routine and passed through this integration path.

Does anyone have any idea why the Marshaller (JaxBMarshaller) throws this exception after the message being serialized. I mean, the message was sucessfully generated, and then after throws the exception, like a problem with the XSD like a "incorrect character code in the xsd file" can cause such message? I am asking because such XML serialization was tested before, and no exception was thrown.

Here is the SI (4.1.2) XML Fragment.

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="jms0503"></int:publish-subscribe-channel>
    <int:chain input-channel="wsAceite0503ResponseChannel" - **WS Response.** 
        output-channel="jms0503">
        <int:transformer ref="saogSaoMsgSOL0503Transformer" 
            method="apply"></int:transformer>
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="protocoloSAOG"
                expression="XXXXX"></int:header>
        <int:header name="XXXXXX" value="XXXXXXX" />        
    </int:header-enricher>          
    <int:transformer id="saogMarsahllerTransformer" ref="saogMarshallingTransformer"></int:transformer>
    <int:object-to-string-transformer></int:object-to-string-transformer>
```

HEre is where the exception is thrown.

Now my doubt is if the exception is being thrown during the schema validation (which my guess is not the case).

```
<stream:stdout-channel-adapter channel="jms0503"></stream:stdout-channel-adapter>           
    <int:chain input-channel="jms0503">
        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter
            connection-factory="solicitacaoConnFactory" destination="XXXXXXX">
        </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
    </int:chain>    
    <int-xml:validating-filter schema-type="xml-schema"
                input-channel="jms0503" throw-exception-on-rejection="true"
                schema-location="solicitacao/SaogSaoMsgSOL0303.xsd" output-channel="xmlValidationOutputChannel" />
```

The Schema location seems to be correct other XML's are validated successfully using the same integration flow pattern.

```
[2015-10-09 15:02:57]ERROR[task-scheduler-5](SaogIntegracaoLogErrorHandler.java:26) - Exception org.springframework.integration.MessageRejectedException: Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.xml.AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException: Multiple causes:
            cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ns13:XXXXXX'.
```

Comment: M-m-m. What is the question? The `AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException` tells you that your XML isn't valid and where... You should log messages before the `<int-xml:validating-filter>` to figure out the wrong `payload` content.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you... Therefore I can't help...

Comment: Thats ok, i understand the origin of the exception, what i asking is who is throwing the object to string or the xml  validation filter.

Comment: Nope. `ObjectToStringTransformer` just does: `return payload.toString();`. So, I don't see issues there.

Comment: Yes you are right, yesterday i understood that probably some invalid character is present in the xml files. will try to check them looking for invalid chars.